# iOS Asynchronous NSURLConnection triggering behaviors on different views than the one that call it

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Me and my team are currently rookie developers in Objective-C (less than 3 months in) working on the development of a simple tab based app with network capabilities that contains a navigator controller with a table view and a corresponding detailed view in each tab. The target is iOS 4 sdk.

On the networking side, we have a single class that functions as a Singleton that processes the NSURLConnection for each one of the views in order to retrieve the data we need for each of the table views.

The functionality works fine and we can retrieve the data correctly but only if the user doesn't change views until the petition is over or the button of the same petition (example: Login button) is pressed on again. Otherwise, different mistakes can happen. For example, an error message that should only be displayed on the root view of one of the navigation controllers appears on the detailed view and vice versa.

We suspect that the issue is that we are currently handling only a single delegate on the Singleton for the "active view" and that we should change it to support a behavior based on the native Mail app in which you can change views while the data that was asked for in each one of the views keeps loading and updating correctly separately.

We have looked over stackoverflow and other websites and we haven't found a proper methodology to follow. We were considering using an NSOperationQueue and wrapping the NSURLConnections on an NSOperation, but we are not sure if that's the proper approach.

Does anyone have any suggestions on the proper way to handle multiple asynchronous NSURLConnections to update multiple views, both parent and child, almost simultaneously at the whim of the user's interaction? Ideally, we don't want to block the UI or disable the buttons as we have been recommended.

Thank you for your time!

Edit - forgot to add, one of the project restrictions set by our client is that we can only use the native iOS sdk network framework and not the ASIHTTPRequest framework or similar. At the same time, we also forgot to add that we are not uploading any information, we are only retrieving it from the WS.

Comment: Do you stop the connections with `cancel` when needed ?

Comment: Thanks for the response! We don't actually want to cancel them when we change screens, we want all of the nsurlconnections to finish properly and send the information to the right view.

Comment: the problem is (and the better solution you see in the answer below) that you have two instances of the connection running if you tap the login button twice. Regarding the UIAlert, it is shown on the top of the window even if is called from the view controller which is not currently say on the top of navigation controller stack, if you don't want to see it neither cancel request, perform the check of currently presented view controller before triggering UIAlert `show`.

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion is to use NSOperations and a NSOperationsQueue. The nice thing about this arrangement is you can quickly cancel any in-process or queued work (if say the user hits the back button.

There is a project on github, [NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy](https://github.com/dhoerl/NSOperation-WebFetches-MadeEasy) that makes this about as painless as it can be. You incorporate one class in your classes - OperationsRunner - which comes with a "how-to-use-me" in OperationsRunner.h, and two skeleton NSOperations classes, one the subclass of another, with the subclass showing how to fetch an image.

I'm sure others will post of other solutions - its almost a problem getting started as there are a huge number of libraries and projects doing this. That said, OperationsRunner is a bit over 100 lines of code, and the operations about the same, so this is really easy to read, understand, use, and modify.

Comment: Yes, this along with KVO are key programming patterns.  Separate your data (model) from your views.  Your network fetches update the data model, and your view update themselves by using something like KVO to react to changes in the model.

Comment: OperationsRunner and the operations have nothing to do with views. The KVO technique is right out of Apple's sample code. Its just so happens in the demo that it updates the view to show that in fact the image arrived - its a Demo project. I'm using OperationsRunner in an app in the store with a 5 star rating and over 10000 users so its not like this is play code. And its used often as is with NO UI elements at all involved.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your singleton has a delegate. Delegation is inappropriate when multiple objects are interested in the result. If you wish to continue using a singleton for fetching data, you must switch your pattern to be based on notifications. Your singleton will have responsibility for determining which connection corresponds to which task, and choosing an appropriate notification to be posted.

If you still need help with this, let me know, I'll try to post some sample code.